# If, else, elif loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up a loop when making squares from *. If box_size is even it's supposed to make a solid square. If box_size is odd it's supposed to make a square outline. This is supposed to go on till the user inputs 0 and the program stops. I've mushed the two codes together however the even code works while the odd code doesn't.

```
#Input
while True:
    box_size=input("box_size:" )
    box_size=int(box_size)
    if box_size % 2:
        break
    for row in range(box_size):
      for col in range(box_size*2):
        print('*', end='')
      print()
    print()

while True:
    box_size= int(input("box size: "))
    if box_size % 1:
        print('*' * box_size)
        for i in range(box_size-2):
            print ('*' + ' ' * (box_size-2) + '*')
            print('*' * box_size)

#Output
box_size:6
************
************
************
************
************
************

box_size:5
box size:
```

Comment: `box_size % 1` doesn't make sense as every integer is divisible by 1. You probably wanted to write `box_size % 2`.

Comment: True. Wasn't sure what to put there so I just stuck the % 2. However, the code still isn't working the way I want it to even if I change that part.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues here and you seem to have been confused because you posted so many questions with bits and pieces of the actual problem you are dealing with.

The `while` clause is probably not required as you only want to run this once. Also you can check if the number is odd or even once the user enters it, so there is no need to ask it twice. So a working version would be:

```
box_size=input("box_size:" )
box_size=int(box_size)
if box_size % 2:
    print('*' * box_size)
    for i in range(box_size-2):
        print ('*' + ' ' * (box_size-2) + '*')
    print('*' * box_size)
else:
    for row in range(box_size):
        for col in range(box_size*2):
            print('*', end='')
        print()
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just made modification on your code.

```
while True:
    box_size=int(input("box_size:" ))
    if box_size == 0:
        break
    elif box_size % 2:
        print(box_size * '*')
        for col in range(box_size-2):
            print ('*' + (box_size-2) * ' ' + '*')
        print(box_size * '*')
    else:
        for row in range(box_size):
            for col in range(box_size*2):
                print('*', end='')
            print()
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
flag= False
while not flag:
    box_size=int(input("box_size:" ))
    if box_size == 0:
        flag=True 
    elif not box_size % 2:
        for row in range(box_size):
            print(2*box_size*'*')
    else:
        print(2*box_size*'*')
        for row in range(1,box_size-1):
            print('*'+2*(box_size-1)*' '+'*')
        print(2*box_size*'*')
```

Output:

```
box_size:6
************
************
************
************
************
************
box_size:5
**********
*        *
*        *
*        *
**********
box_size:0
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this?

```
while True:
    box_size=input("box_size:" )
    box_size=int(box_size)
    if box_size == 0:
        break # program stops
    elif box_size % 2 == 0: # even numbers
        for row in range(box_size):
            for col in range(box_size*2):
                print('*', end='')
            print()
        print()
    else: # odd numbers
        print('*' * box_size)
        for i in range(box_size-2):
            print ('*' + ' ' * (box_size-2) + '*')
        print('*' * box_size)
```

I assume you meant that the program will continue running to prompt for another `box_size` until the user eventually enters `0` as input.